# Disable right click file printing in windows?

Tags: windows, desktop

Is this possible to disable or remove the right click on a file print option? Seems like it should be possible.

Comment: Why per se is this a problem? If you don't want users to print don't install printers.

Comment: It's super irritating when you want to right click to "edit" (view) a file and mouse click lands on print instead.

Comment: I printed my batch file 3 times today, when I just wanted to 'edit'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those kinds of options on the right-click menu are assigned per file type. If you're only interested in targeting a few file types, you can remove the print command from those file types.

For example, for PDF documents, go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.pdf` and look at the default value. On my computer, the value is `AcroExch.Document`. So then you would go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AcroExch.Document\Shell` and delete the print subkey.

Answer (score 11):

Although you evidently have to remove these registry keys for individual file types, this is the most comprehensive list for it that I've found:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;--------
;-------- Remove "Print" from context menu for image files
;--------
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\print]


;-------- 
;-------- Remove Print From common text-based files
;-------- 
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\text\shell\print]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\print]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\shell\print]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\docfile\shell\print]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\fonfile\shell\print]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\htmlfile\shell\print]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\inffile\shell\print]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\inifile\shell\print]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\JSEFile\shell\print]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\JSFile\shell\print]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSInfo.Document\shell\print]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\otffile\shell\print]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pfmfile\shell\print]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\regfile\shell\print]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rtffile\shell\print]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ttcfile\shell\print]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ttffile\shell\print]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\print]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBEFile\shell\print]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\shell\print]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wordpad.Document.1\shell\print]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WPEDoc\shell\print]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WPSDoc\shell\print]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\wrifile\shell\print]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WSFFile\shell\print]

;-------- 
;-------- Remove Print From Internet Shortcut
;-------- 
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\InternetShortcut\shell\print]

;-------- 
;-------- Remove Print From Acrobat-/Foxit-registered .pdf files
;-------- 
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AcroExch.Document.7\shell\print]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\FoxitReader.Document\shell\print]
```

You can copy and paste this into a file of type .reg and double-click it to run it.

From [here](http://fragme.blogspot.com/2007/07/windows-tip-18-remove-unnecessary-right.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can disable Explorer's context menu with a GPO.

Comment: Is it possible to edit the context menu to only disable the print option? As the other options should still be able

Comment: Not that I know of. Why do you need to disable the ability to print? You may need to look into AD RMS.

Comment: `Is it possible to edit the context menu to only disable the print option?` Yes, this is possible, as the context menu (and all its entries) are controlled by simple registry keys.  The `Print` option, however, is held in multiple keys (one per file type), which makes it a pain to get rid of.  Maybe I'll post a how-to after work, if my new game isn't waiting for me when I get home, but honestly, the better approach is to just ignore it, and/or severely beat users who bug you about it so they shut up.

Answer (score 2):

For entire classes, and this works especially well to get rid of EDIT and PRINT for all images (which are useless entries, in my opinion), go to:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image`, go to the node containing the command you want to disable, and make a new STRING value entitled "LegacyDisable" under that node.

So, for example, if you want to disable "edit", go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\edit`, and make a new STRING value entitled "LegacyDisable" under that node.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `REG QUERY` to pull back an array of registry items that end in `'shell\print'`.  Using an elevated PowerShell prompt you can filter the results and pipe to `REG DELETE` to remove them.

```
# get an array of 
$regprint = REG QUERY HKCR /f print /s /e /k | ?{$_ -like '*shell\print'}
# here you can check the array to make sure it is what you want to remove
# and you can pipe it into REG DELETE
$regprint.foreach({REG DELETE $_ /va /f})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ShellMenuView to edit or disable any context menu item, and you can also jump to the registry entry for editing.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html

[image: ShellMenuView]

Answer (score 1):

`disable_print.bat`

```
@setlocal
@echo off

echo wait ~minute

@for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('REG QUERY HKCR /f print /e /s /k ^| findstr /i /r .print$')     
do (
    echo %%a
    reg add %%a /v LegacyDisable /t REG_SZ
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Love the answers posted, but I prefer to hide/disable. [source](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-clean-up-your-messy-windows-context-menu/)

> If you want to hide one of these items so that you’ll have to
>   Shift+Right-Click, then you can add a new string value on the
>   right-hand side and name it “**Extended**” like you can see below:

[image]

> If you’d like to disable it instead, but don’t want to delete the key,
>   you can add a new string value and call it “**LegacyDisable**”.

[image]